# How to get row number in dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the number of the row in a dataframe that contains a certain value in a certain column using Pandas? For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
     ClientID  LastName
0    34        Johnson
1    67        Smith
2    53        Brows
```

How can I find the number of the row that has 'Smith' in 'LastName' column?

Comment: Try this: `df.LastName.eq('Smith').sum()`

Comment: @MaxU That will return the total number of rows containing the last name "Smith", not the individual row numbers.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

*Note that a dataframe's index could be out of order, or not even numerical at all. If you don't want to use the current index and instead renumber the rows sequentially, then you can use `df.reset_index()` together with the suggestions below*

To get all indices that matches 'Smith'

```
>>> df[df['LastName'] == 'Smith'].index
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

or as a numpy array

```
>>> df[df['LastName'] == 'Smith'].index.to_numpy()  # .values on older versions
array([1])
```

or if there is only one and you want the integer, you can subset

```
>>> df[df['LastName'] == 'Smith'].index[0]
1
```

You could use the same boolean expressions with `.loc`, but it is not needed unless you also want to select a certain column, which is redundant when you only want the row number/index.

Comment: In general, an index and a row number are different. For example, the index could refer to the row numbers of the original DataFrame, and we could be working on a subset of the original. So a different method is needed; perhaps one could reset the index before treating row numbers as indices.

Comment: @JS1204 Yes the index could be out of order, or not even numerical at all. If you don't want to use the current index and instead renumber the rows sequentially, then you can use `df.reset_index()` first as you noted.

Comment: This gives the index and not the row number. The index can be anything including a string depending on source of the dataframe. While in most cases it will work it does not do what the question asked for.

Answer (score 13):

```
df.index[df.LastName == 'Smith']
```

Or

```
df.query('LastName == "Smith"').index
```

Will return all row indices where `LastName` is `Smith`

```
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: if there is only one and you want the integer, just subset: `df.index[df.LastName == 'Smith'][0]`

Answer (score 8):

```
df.loc[df.LastName == 'Smith']
```

will return the row

```
    ClientID    LastName
1   67          Smith
```

and

```
df.loc[df.LastName == 'Smith'].index
```

will return the index

```
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

NOTE: Column names 'LastName' and 'Last Name' or even 'lastname' are three unique names. The best practice would be to first check the exact name using df.columns. If you really need to strip the column names of all the white spaces, you can first do

```
df.columns = [x.strip().replace(' ', '') for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: What if the column name has a space in the middle (e.g. Last Name). How will the line `df.loc[df.LastName == 'Smith'].index` change?

Comment: @ sprogissd, pl see the NOTE in the answer

Comment: what if there is more than one Smith?

Comment: @Joseph Garvin, This code will return the indices of all the positions where LastName is Smith. If I add another Smith in the sample dataframe above and run the code, i get Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')

Answer (score 2):

```
 len(df[df["Lastname"]=="Smith"].values)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's many years later but don't try the above solutions without reindexing your dataframe first. As many have pointed out already the number you see to the left of the dataframe 0,1,2 in the initial question is the index INSIDE that dataframe. When you extract a subset of it with a condition you might end up with 0,2 or 2,1, or 2,1 or 2,1,0 depending your condition. So by using that number (called "index") you will not get the position of the row in the subset. You will get the position of that row inside the main dataframe.

use:

```
np.where([df['LastName'] == 'Smith'])[1][0]
```

and play with the string 'Smith' to see the various outcomes. Where will return 2 arrays. The 2nd one (index 1) is the one you care about.

NOTE:
When the value you search for does not exist where() will return 0 on [1][0]. When is the first value of the list it will also return 0 on [1][0]. Make sure you validate the existence first.

NOTE #2:
In case the same value as in your condition is present in the subset multiple times on [1] with will find the list with the position of all occurrences. You can use the length of [1] for future processing if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If the index of the dataframe and the ordinal number of the rows differ, most solutions posted here won't work anymore. Given your dataframe with an **alphabetical** index:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"ClientID": {"A": 34, "B": 67, "C": 53}, "LastName": {"A": "Johnson", "B": "Smith", "C": "Brows"}})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   ClientID LastName
A        34  Johnson
B        67    Smith
C        53    Brows
```

You have to use [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to access the ordinal row number:

```
In [4]: df.index.get_loc(df.query('LastName == "Smith"').index[0])
Out[4]: 1
```

If there may exist multiple rows where the condition holds, e.g. find the ordinal row numbers that have 'Smith' *or* 'Brows' in `LastName` column, you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [5]: [df.index.get_loc(idx) for idx in df.query('LastName == "Smith" | LastName == "Brows"').index]
Out[5]: [1, 2]
```

Comment: this seems the only real answer, the question spoke about row number, not index label

Answer (score 1):

```
count_smiths = (df['LastName'] == 'Smith').sum()
```

Comment: That will return the total number of rows containing the last name "Smith", not the individual row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use shape method
`df[df['LastName'] == 'Smith'].shape`

**Output**
`(1,1)`

Which indicates 1 row and 1 column. This way you can get the idea of whole datasets

Let me explain the above code
`DataframeName[DataframeName['Column_name'] == 'Value to match in column']`

Answer (score 1):

If in the question "row number" means actual row number/position (rather than index label)
[pandas.Index.get_loc(key, method=None, tolerance=None)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)
seems to be the answer, ie something like:

```
row_number = df.index.get_loc(df.query(f'numbers == {m}').index[0])
```

The current answers, except one, explain how to get the index label rather than  the row number.
Trivial code with index lables not corresponding to row numbers:

```
import pandas as pd

n = 3; m = n-1

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers' : range(n) },
    index = range(n-1,-1,-1))
print(df,"\n")

label =      df[df['numbers'] == m].index[0]
row_number = df.index.get_loc(df.query(f'numbers == {m}').index[0])

print(f'index label: {label}\nrow number:  {row_number}',"\n")
print(f"df.loc[{label},'numbers']: {df.loc[label, 'numbers']}")
print(f"df.iloc[{row_number}, 0]:       {df.iloc[row_number, 0]}")
```

```
   numbers
2        0
1        1
0        2 

index label: 0
row number:  2 

df.loc[0,'numbers']: 2
df.iloc[2, 0]:       2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To get exact row-number of single occurrence

`row-number = df[df["LastName" == 'Smith']].index[0]`

2. To get exact row-number of multiple occurrence of 'Smith'

`row-number = df[df["LastName" == 'Smith']].index.tolist()`