# How can I get the index number of a row in a pivoted table with python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this pivot table, 'movieUser_df':

[image]

And I need to be able to get the index number of any row based on userID.

I can locate the row easily enough like this:

```
movieUser_df.loc[movieUser_df.index.values == "641c87d06a97e629837fc079"]
```

But it only returns the row data.

I thought just `movieUser_df.index == "641c87d06a97e629837fc079"` might work, but it just returns this:

[image]

I'm assuming it's booleans for whether each column for the row is 0 or not 0, but in reverse for some reason (as the first item in the returned array is true, despite the only column having value other than 0 in the row in movieUser_df being the very last datapoint.), but I'm not sure.

I've looked around for solutions/other people with this problem, but all I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646153/pandas-pivot-table-get-index-of-certain-row), but unless I'm missing something, they end up asking a completely different question in the questions body.

Anyway, does anyone know how I can get the row index number by userID in this situation? Let me know if there's any more info I can provide that could be helpful, thanks for any help.

Comment: The userID is the row index. When you say "row index" - what value are you trying to find exactly? Do you mean like "row number 10"?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes that's what I meant, index number of the row

Comment: The `True, False, ...` array is telling you where the matches are. You can use `np.where` to get only the indexes of the true values: `np.where(movieUser_df.index == ...)`

Comment: Why not reset the index then? Seems like you don't actually want `userID` to be the index and just want a range index instead?

Comment: I'm looking for only the placement of the row in the table, so in the example above where I'm looking for the row where userID is '641c87d06a97e629837fc079', the output I'm looking for is just '0', or if I look for userID with 'ur99999734' (the last one in the table) it would return just '21177'.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a range index: `movieUser_df = movieUser_df.reset_index(); movieUser_df[movieUser_df.userID=='641c87d06a97e629837fc079'].index`

Comment: (But @jqurious's `np.where` will work fine without changing indexes)

Comment: Oh I see, I just tested both solutions and both work and I can see how now, thank you both very much!

Answer (score 0):

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193880/how-to-get-row-number-in-dataframe-in-pandas). In your dataframe, userID is the index. To get the number of the row, you can [use numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
  index=['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
  columns=['tt1', 'tt2'])


np.argmax(df.index == "user1") 
# 0
```